Incorrect AAB installation
I'm facing the problem of installing AAB (the app's published on the playmarket) on Nexus 5X
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800f9
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:224)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValueForDensity(Resources.java:1334)
       at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:798)
       at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:754)

AAB has the following apk files:

base-hdpi.apk
base-ldpi.apk
base-master.apk
base-master_2.apk
base-mdpi.apk
base-tvdpi.apk
base-xhdpi.apk
base-xxhdpi.apk
base-xxxhdpi.apk
and other locale apks

I decided to download these apks to the Nexus 5X emulator
When I download the bundle of density and master apks (e.g. base-master.apk with base-hdpi.apk), everything works fine, but when I download only the master or master_2 apk, I get the above error
Update: I found the reason of the crash: I had one png image in three drawable packages (drawable, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi), when I deleted drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi and kept only the drawable package the above crash was fixed, but I wanna keep drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi packages too, 'cause there're different sizes of that image there
I tried to create drawable packages with all densities (xxx-high, xx-high, x-high, high, medium, low, any, no), but it didn't help

Not every device requires all APK files only install the matching APK files. But I am a bit confused you were talking about an aab file and then about the APK files  but Android app bundles (aab files) do not contain APK files, they have a different internal structure. Have you created the AaPK files via bundletool?

Yes, i ve created .apks file via bundletool, then converted it into a zip with toc.pb and splits containing .apk files
I understand that device installs only the matching APK files, but why does it work correctly without any crashes on other devices? I think the problem is with density: the device can't detect density, so it doesn't install any apk file of density, causing the above crash

Why don't you let bundletool chose which APKs are required? Just use the --connected-device parameter so bundletool will only build those APKs that are required/usable with your device.

Thanks, I tried this: in the Nexus 5x emulator it creates three apks (base-en, base-master, base-xxhdpi), and everything works fine
But now i don't know how to recreate the above mentioned crash from the crashlytics

Fixed crash by deleting all drawable packages except default one

This is the correct behaviour. Google Play will choose one apk only to be installed on the device. you have nothing to worry about.

Sorry but this is wrong, Google will not install one APK but a set of APKs matching to your device.
